# Why isnt my process being suspended even though im suspending the PID?

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, suspend

So I just started with process suspending and I've been looking around at different methods and one that caught my attention was this method..

The code you will see below takes the process id (PID) of the notepad that was opened before I started the application and then it should suspend it?
Atleast thats what I've been reading but when I run this it doesnt suspend it at all. How come?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<Windows.h>

using namespace std;


void suspend()
{
    DWORD processId = 0x8788; 
    DebugActiveProcess(processId);
    system("pause");
    return;
}

void main() {
    suspend();
    return;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you check the return value of `DebugActiveProcess` and call `GetLastError` like the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms679295(v=vs.85).aspx) suggests?

Comment: Your program probably doesn't have the required (SE DEBUG PRIV) priviledge to attach another program as a debugger. Check for the returned value of `DebugActiveProcess(processId);`

Comment: It is the winapi function that a debugger uses to attach to a running process.  This code does not resemble the kind that a debugger uses.  Lots and lots of sample code out there to show you how to write your own debugger.  But it is generally sane to not reinvent that wheel.

Comment: Im currently trying open the process from the application with all access and then see if that will work!